# Mysql return on item from different location based on location id and coordinate

Tags: mysql, arrays, coordinates

Am trying to select all items from `item_table` based on user distance from the seller stores. Below code actually work fine till i use `FIND_IN_SET` to allow showing one product in two or more different location if the location `loc_id` is in array of item `item_loc_ids`.

What i actually want to archive is to show one product to users from different locations provided the store coordinate is within the user location and the location `ID` is in list of locations where the item should be available based on distance calculation.

seller_table

```
seller_name      | seller_id   
-----------------|-----------------
 Peter           | PP1
 John            | JJ6
```

location_table

```
 loc_name  | loc_id   |  loc_lat  | loc_lng     | seller_id
-----------|----------|-----------|-------------|----------
 Office 1  | 1A       | 2.908810  | 101.651398  | PP1
 Office 2  | 1B       | 3.051953  | 101.671417  | PP1
 Outlet S  | 3A       | 3.051953  | 101.671455  | JJ6
```

Item_table

```
 item_name  | item_id  | item_loc_ids   | item_seller
 -----------|----------|----------------|------------------
 Java       | 1        | 1A, 1B         | PP1
 PHP        | 2        | 1A             | PP1
 CSS        | 3        | 1B             | PP1
 SQL        | 4        | 1B, 1A         | PP1
 Python     | 5        | 3A             | JJ6
```

User Data

```
 $userLatitude = 2.908810;
 $userLongitude = 101.651398;
 $userDistance  = 5.5;
```

Query

```
SELECT seller.*,loc.*, item.*, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((loc.loc_lat - ABS($userLatitude)) * PI()/180 / 2), 2) + COS(loc.loc_lng * PI()/180 ) * COS(ABS( $userLatitude) * PI()/180)  * POWER(SIN((loc.loc_lng - $userLongitude) * PI()/180 / 2), 2))) AS distance
FROM (
    SELECT item.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item.item_seller ORDER BY Item.item_seller) AS limit_group
    FROM Item_table Item
) p
INNER JOIN seller_name seller
ON Item.item_seller = seller.seller_id

INNER JOIN location_table loc
ON FIND_IN_SET(loc.loc_id, Item.item_loc_ids)

WHERE limit_group <= 5
    HAVING distance <=  $userDistance 
    OR distance IS NULL
    ORDER BY distance IS NULL DESC, distance DESC
LIMIT 100
```

The above code work only on one location_id, but if more it won't return any record.

I added a link to sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c085b/4

and DDLs of same:

```
 CREATE TABLE `location_table` (
    `loc_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `loc_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `loc_lat` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `loc_lng` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `seller_id` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

 INSERT INTO `location_table` (`loc_name`, `loc_id`, `loc_lat`, `loc_lng`, `seller_id`) 
 VALUES ('Office 1', '1A', '2.908810', '101.651398', 'PP1'),  
 ('Office 1', '1B', '3.051953', '101.671417', 'PP1'),
 ('Outlet S', '3A', '3.051953', '101.671455', 'JJ6');


CREATE TABLE `seller_table` (
    `seller_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `seller_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `seller_table` (`seller_name`, `seller_id`) VALUES ('Peter', 'PP1'),  ('John', 'JJ6');


 CREATE TABLE `item_table` (
    `item_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `item_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `item_store_ids` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `item_seller` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

  INSERT INTO `item_table` (`item_name`, `item_id`, `item_store_ids`, `item_seller`) VALUES ('Java', '1', '1A, 1B ', 'PP1'), 
  ('PHP', '2', '1A ', 'PP1'), 
  ('CSS', '3', '1B ', 'PP1'), 
  ('SQL', '4', '1B, 1A ', 'PP1'),
  ('Python', '5', '3A ', 'JJ6');

  SELECT seller.*,loc.*, item.*, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((loc.loc_lat - ABS(2.908810)) * PI()/180 / 2), 2) + COS(loc.loc_lng * PI()/180 ) * COS(ABS(2.908810) * PI()/180)  * POWER(SIN((loc.loc_lng - 101.651398) * PI()/180 / 2), 2))) AS distance
FROM (
    SELECT item.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item.item_seller ORDER BY item.item_seller) AS limit_group
    FROM item_table item
) p
INNER JOIN seller_table seller
ON item.item_seller = seller.seller_id

INNER JOIN location_table loc
ON FIND_IN_SET(loc.loc_id, item.item_store_ids)

WHERE limit_group <= 5
    HAVING distance <=  5.5 
    OR distance IS NULL
    ORDER BY distance IS NULL DESC, distance DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Please send table create code and insert statements. Finally expected output format.

Comment: Since you are using `ROW_NUMBER()` you have at least MySQL 8.0 - So why don't you use `ST_Distance()` or `ST_Distance_Sphere()`?

Comment: @JitendraYadav okay i will update my question with a link to table

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i will love to if you can give me a sample query, before i could get query working it too 6 days before my question was answered

Comment: See: [ST_Distance_Sphere()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere) and [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/R1iF5Ltna2pWYYGrTAenc/0)

Comment: Also see: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @JitendraYadav I have updated my question

Comment: @PaulSpiegel please i don't think my question is same with the answered reference which was marked.

Comment: @Peter, the suggested design from Paul is good. But I think for your scenario, you can just update your on clause by this `FIND_IN_SET(loc.loc_id, REPLACE(Item.item_store_ids, ' ', ''))`

Comment: @Peter I didn't close the question. I only posted the link.

Comment: See additional duplicate references. You need to remove the spaces after the comma. If that doesn't help, then it's unclear what you are asking.